# Change only some of the values of the current route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

My search page has a lot of parameters and in this page I have some filters for the current search.
I just want to change some of the values in my route.

An example:

```
http://www.example.com/{controller}/{action}/{brand}/{model}/{color}/{price}
```

In my search page I have a form where I can change the color and the price:

HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Color, Model.Colors)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Price, Model.Prices)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(SearchModel search)
{
    //I can get the Price and Color
    string color = search.Color;
    string price = search.Price;

    //Now I want to get the values of brand and model

    return RedirectToRoute("Action",new
    {
         controller = "Controller",
         action = "Action",
         color = color,
         price = price,
         brand = ????,
         model = ????
    });

}
```

My search has a lot more parameters than this... I don't want to put them in hidden fields and send them with the model :\

Thanks

Comment: What is it exactly that you do not want? Hidden fields? If these are your search parameters, then they should be visible to the user, no? Or is a case where user input may change the params that will be sent for the search?

Comment: Hi! I just want to catch in the controller the brand and model values (in this example). The user input will only change the color and price values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put them in the QueryString instead? Then it'll look like this:

http://www.example.com/something.aspx?color=red&price=100

Then you can pick up what you want , ignore the rest, and the order won't matter.

Hope this answers your question, didn't really understand it to be honest.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear but your answer will not match my route: http://www.example.com/{controller}/{action}/{brand}/{model}/{color}/{price} What I want basically is after the user submits the form the user will be redirected to the url with the new values of color and price and maintain the values of brand and model.

Answer (score 0):

I found  a solution.

I need to do this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("action", 
                       "controller", 
                       new { brand = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["brand"],
                             model = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["model"] },
                             FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Color, Model.Colors)
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Price, Model.Prices)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

}
```

Then in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Action(SearchModel search)
{

    return RedirectToRoute("Action",new
    {
         controller = "Controller",
         action = "Action",
         color = search.Color,
         price = search.Price,
         brand = search.Brand,
         model = search.Model
    });

}
```

If anyone knows another solution please let me know.
Thank you.